# Is it a bad idea to pour water on a pan without letting it cool off?

Tags: cookware, chemistry

Obviously I have enough common sense to not add pour water into boiling oil, but after the cooking is done I try to add water to the pan so it's easier to wash. Usually I let it sit there cooling off and more often than not I just forget about it and have the biohazard that is a greasy cast iron ribbed pan to deal with in the morning.
If the pan is still somewhat hot and you feel it's warm feel 3-4 inches above the surface of the cookware is it fine to add water? Can it damage the pan in the long run?

Comment: What kind of pan?

Comment: This site looks more and more as metallurgy SE. I thought seasoned referred to aromas and tastes but probably it is about pans :))

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the pan and how hot the pan is ; glass pan is likely a problem, and some of the glass-like decorative coatings on metal pans are a risk. Otherwise temperatures would need to be well above cooking temperatures to even consider damage to a metal pan. Hot enough that the water will "bounce" out of the pan because of rapid steam development.  Aluminum could be a problem at 800 F ( Melting begins around 1000 F ). Magnetic stainless ( 13 % Cr)  is happy as auto exhaust to 1400 F ( red). Non-magnetic stainless ( 18-8 ) will go higher. Cast-iron and copper can go 1300 F + ( dim red) : however the tin coating on older copper will be destroyed above 600 F... BUT , some pans will warp even at normal cooking temps; I have had a couple inexpensive aluminum frying pans develop a rounded bottom so they won't sit flat on the stove (no water cooling involved)